# Extract identical key, value from a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict (dict_genes) containing gene id's as the keys.

I want to iterate through this dict and use the gene id's (keys) to extract values from another dict (seq_depth) such as:

```
for key, value in dict_genes.items():   
     print(seq_depth[key])
```

The dict seq_depth contains several identical gene id's and with this approach only one occurrence is printed where I want all of the gene id's printed if the match the key in the iteration (including indenticals).

Answer (score 1):

For dictionaries you cannot have more than one of the same key. Instead, I would suggest using a dictionary whose keys point to lists of values:

```
seq_depth = {"id": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]}
```

Comment: Using a `defaultdict(list)` can help build such structures more easily.

Comment: I have bypassed this by using defaultdict so my dictionary does contain identical keys